# Why doesn't my function with variables update data?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def overwriteFlat(top, curTable, rawEntrylist, columns): 
    rawEntrylist = rawEntrylist
    entryList = list()
    for value in rawEntrylist:
        entryList.append(value.get())  
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    for i in range(len(columns)):
        if entryList[i] != '':
            c.execute("""UPDATE """+curTable+""" SET """+columns[i]+""" = :"""+columns[i]+""" WHERE """+columns[0]+""" = """ + str(entryList[0]), {columns[i]: entryList[i]})
            print(curTable,columns[i],entryList[i])
            conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close() 
    closeWin(top)
```

Output:

```
Flat ID 23
Flat Street Test
Flat Street_Number 100
```

I put in "Test" and "100" so that works. I provide a window for input, the input gets put into here and everything provided gets overwritten in provided ID. Because of `print()` I see it goes into the right table, it also selects the right column and doesn't throw any exception. But it doesn't update database.

- Database not locked.
- Variables all valid and work.
- No exception is thrown.
- Vulnerable to injection, soon as it works I'll change it.

Comment: This way of executing sql is vulnerable to injection attacks.  Don't do it this way.

Comment: I bet if you printed the entire statement, instead of just the variables, the error would be obvious.

Comment: Yes, i put that in the edit and i will change that in the future, but first i gotta make it work :) if i change anything now ill just break it more

Comment: @JohnGordon how would i print that?

Comment: Copy everything inside the `c.execute()` statement, and put it in a`print()` statement.

Comment: Or even easier, make a copy of that whole line and change `c.execute` to `print`.

Comment: UR A GOD THANKS SO MUCH i didnt know i could do that, and i found the issue now!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JohnGordon i found the solution

But just so if someone wants to use Variables in Sqlite i will explain how as this is hardly explained anywhere on the Internet (at least at my Beginner-Programmer-Level)

Usually Sql commands work like this and are pretty static:

```
"UPDATE Your_Table SET Your_Column = :Your_Column WHERE IndexColumn = Your_Index), {Your_Column: Your_Value}"
```

But by using +Variable+ you can use Variables in there
so its the same thing but with whatever Variable you want:

```
"UPDATE "+curTable+" SET "+columns[i]+" = :"+columns[i]+" WHERE "+columns[i]+" = " + str(entryList[0]), {columns[i]: entryList[i]}
```

You can now have the Variables "curTable", "columns", "entryList" set to whatever you want and dont need a static line for everything
The same works with INSERT and the other things too

Edit: (its now 3 hours later, 1 AM and i got the safer way)

**NOW THAT YOU GOT THAT READ THIS**
you will be vulnerable to SQL Injection, and you need to still change that code to this:

```
query = " UPDATE "+curTable+" SET "+columns[i]+" = ? WHERE "+columns[0]+" = ?"
        c.execute(query, (entryList[i], entryList[0], ))
```

this makes it safer, but as i am not a pro yet maybe someone can confirm

Edit: Removed triple-quotes as they are only needed in multiple-sentence sql stuff thanks for the hint @Tim Roberts

Comment: Why are you using triple-quotes?  There's no point to that here, and it's both harder to type and harder to read.  Just do `f"UPDATE {curTable} SET {columns[i]}=:{columns[i]} WHERE {columns[0]}=:YourIndex"`.

Comment: @TimRoberts didnt yet go deep enough into sql programming to understand how your solution works exactly, but mine works and i think its safer for sql injection than my first even more primitive solution

Comment: No.  I assumed you were using the ":IndexColumn" notation to do the substitution.  Some databases do it that way, some use the "?" character.  All I'm doing is constructing the query string, using a better method than building it with a+b+c+d.  My primary point was about the triple-quotes, which you have now removed.